# Techniques for finding patterns in binary data

Tags: binary-data, pattern-recognition

I have a question about data analysis and I am wondering if someone can advise? I am interested in what mathematical techniques are available to look for patterns in binary data.

Say I have a black box that spits out balls in sequence at seemingly random time intervals. The balls could be either red or blue and so I have data on the color of each ball and the time it was produced from the box. Are there any mathematical techniques available to investigate whether any non-random patterns might be present in that data (e.g. is there a higher chance of a blue ball following a red ball? Are there any particular 'blocks' of patterns that repeat more often than others?)? I would be interested in looking at the stream of binary data, both with and without the time information. If so, what general area of analysis would that be?

I am not very experienced in data analysis and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: A Markov chain would be a good starting point

Comment: @jcken ok, thanks for the tip! I have vaguely heard of 'Markov chains', but I'm not familiar with their usage.

Comment: Ignoring the time information, this is the study of *pseudorandom number generators.*  There's a large literature on it.  With time information, not so much, because it depends on what you mean by "non-random pattern" and that starts to become complex when the time stamps are included.

Comment: @whuber that's a good point. Without the time info, it is basically the same thing as a series of coin flips, which may or may not be 'random'. So, I can see that similar techniques could be used to investigate how random or not the data is. Thanks!

Comment: You might use a runs test to check whether the alternation btw red and blue is random..